# Books on Mu-Calculus

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, mu-calculus, formal-systems

I need a book on [Mu-Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_calculus) with lots of examples that can be used for self-study and preparation for exams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An excellent book is [Rudiments of $\mu$-calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444506209). It's not cheap though. You'd be better of learning from survey articles such as

- [Bradfield, Julian and Stirling, Colin. Modal mu-calculi. In: P. Blackburn, J. van Benthem and F. Wolter (eds.), The Handbook of Modal Logic pp. 721-756. Elsevier (2006)](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jcb/Research/MLH-bradstir.pdf) or
- [Bradfield, J. C. and Stirling, C. P. Modal logics and mu-calculi: an introduction. In Handbook of Process Algebra (eds. J. Bergstra, A. Ponse and S. Smolka) 293--330. Elsevier (2001).](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jcb/Research/bradfield-stirling-HPA-mu-intro.ps.gz)